# Adding an element to the middle of a malloc array

Tags: arrays, c, malloc, realloc

I've created a function that allows an element to be deleted from my malloc(ed) array (a list of struct triangle coordinates). That works fine.
But when I tried to create one that adds an element (after position i) it just won't work...

For example, if I had an array of [0] [1] [2] [3] [4] [5] and wanted to add a new value after [3].

Here is my code: (this is a snippet of inside my while loop)

```
totaltri++;
addtriangle(trilist, totaltri, i);
i++;
secondtriangle(p, &t1, &t2, &t3, v, i);
i++;
```

My code deletetriangle(....):

```
for (int c = i; c < totaltri; c++)
{
     trilist[c] = trilist[c+1];
}

tmp = (triangle *) realloc(trilist, (totaltri-1)*sizeof(triangle));

trilist = tmp;
```

And my code addtriangle(....): Which doesn't seem to work..!

```
tmp = (triangle *) realloc(trilist, (totaltri+1)*sizeof(triangle));

for (int c = totaltri; c > i; c--)
{
    trilist[c-1] = trilist[c];
}
trilist = tmp;
```

I then proceed to assign values to the second triangle that has just been added in this code:

```
    int p1, p2, p3;
    p1  = whereisthepoint(p, *t1, v);
    p2  = whereisthepoint(p, *t2, v);
    p3  = whereisthepoint(p, *t3, v);

    triptr=&(trilist[i]);
    triptr->corner=(point *) malloc(3*sizeof(point));
    pt1ptr=&(triptr->corner[0]);
    pt2ptr=&(triptr->corner[1]);
    pt3ptr=&(triptr->corner[2]);

        pt3ptr->x=t3->x; etc etc
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You have to assign the value of previous element to the next element. Your assignment is reversed.
- `trilist` is invalidated via `realloc()` so you should use `tmp` for shifting.
- You have to assign the new value to add that.
- Casting results of `malloc()` family is [considered as a bad practice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc).

`addtriangle(....):` should be like this:

```
tmp = realloc(trilist, (totaltri+1)*sizeof(triangle));

for (int c = totaltri; c > i; c--)
{
    tmp[c] = tmp[c-1]; /* correctly shift the elements */
}
tmp[i] = new_value; /* assign new value (replace new_value with proper thing) */
trilist = tmp;
```

Answer (score 1):

Assume you have a pointer `p` of type `T` declared as such: `T *p;` and you also have an object that you want to add declared as `T x;`

Then just do like this:

```
T *p = malloc(sizeof *p * size);
T x;

...

// Reallocate to make room for one more element
T *tmp = realloc(p, sizeof *p * (size + 1));

// Error checking
if(!tmp) { /* Handle error */ }

p = tmp;

// Move the elements after the insertion spot
memmove(&p[index+1], &p[index], sizeof *p * (size - index));

// And insert
p[index] = x;
```

If you don't care about recovering on an allocation error, you don't need a temporary variable. Then you can just do:

```
p = realloc(p, sizeof *p * (size + 1));

if(!p) exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
tmp = (triangle *) realloc(trilist, (totaltri+1)*sizeof(triangle));

for (int c = totaltri; c > i; c--)
{
    trilist[c-1] = trilist[c];
```

in your code you modify (if realloc was successful) the invalid pointer. `trilist` may not point to the valid memory location. You should use `tmp` instead or assign `trilist` with `tmp`.

Universal function to add to an array.

```
void *addToArr(void *array, size_t arraysize, size_t pos, size_t elemsize, void *element)
{
    unsigned char *ucarray;
    array = realloc(array, (arraysize + 1) * elemsize);
    if(array)
    {
        ucarray = array;
        memmove(ucarray + (pos + 1) * elemsize, ucarray + pos * elemsize, (arraysize - pos) * elemsize);
        memcpy(ucarray + pos * elemsize, element, elemsize);
    }
    return array;
}
```

Comment: What is `ucarray` for?

Comment: Also what is `memove`?

Comment: Also adding integers to `void*` is not allowed in the standard C.

Comment: @0___________ Is there anything wrong with commenting to point out typos so you can correct them?